# Parse math expression using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I want to parse a math expression using regular expression.
For instance, the expression "-4-2-1" is parsed into "-4", "-", "2", "-" and "1". However, from my regex, I can only get "-", "4", "-", "2", "-", "1"

this is my regex `^-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+$|[+-×÷^√∛!πe%]`

Comment: Maybe post your regex ?

Comment: good luck with that. unless you limit yourself to very simple equations, you can't write a regex that'll handle ALL equations.

Comment: For now you can try with `(^-)?\\d*\\.?\\d+|[+\\-×÷^√∛!πe%]`

Comment: it works like a charm, thanks a lot.

Comment: use stack instead of regex and do it manually :)

Comment: how can I do that with stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create regex for all kind of equations, but for your case you can improve your regex by

- making `^-` part optional,
- escaping `-` in your character class (otherwise it will be treated as range operator)

BTW `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?`.

So try with `"(^-)?\\d*\\.?\\d+|[+\\-×÷^√∛!πe%]"`